# Drag an image and to fit in the correct bounding box

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am developing a board game, and I have 10x10 cells in my board, each cell is taken by an UIImageView, so when player tried to place a piece into the cell, the corresponding cell should be set to an image.

What I want to achieve is when user drag a piece and try to put it onto the board, the piece should fit itself into the UIImageView of the cell. The problem now is I can put the piece anywhere on the board, even between two cells. What can I do to fix it? thanks

**----------------Updated:----------------**

Since I did everything in storyboard, so there's very few code I can share hare. I have following line of code in .h file:

```
@property(retain) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *images;
```

They are an array of UIImageView with length 100, each one of them corresponds to a cell in the board, like the following:

[image]

the icons currently on the board are auto generated, the target icon which I want to drag onto the board is located on the upper left of the board ('X' icon). and the following method which handles the drag:

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                         recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
}
```

The problem now is I can place the 'X' anywhere on the board, like the following:

[image] but instead I want to put it to fit into a cell in the board.

Comment: Share some code please. Without code we can't say why this is happening.

Comment: set UIImageView content property. Can you share your set of codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by detecting which cell the translation has ended in. For example:

```
    - (IBAction)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
        CGPoint origin = yourGrid.frame.origin; //where yourGrid refers to the main game board
        float cellHeight = 30; //enter the corresponding value for cellHeight and cellWidth
        float cellWidth = 30; //I've chosen 30 as an arbitrary value.
        int translationXIndex = (recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x - origin.x)/cellWidth;
        int translationYIndex = (recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y - origin.y)/cellHeight;

//Assuming you count left to right and then up to down
        [[images objectAtIndex: (translationXIndex + (10*translationYIndex))] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YourImage.png"]];
        recognizer.view.center = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x,
                                             recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.view];
        //You would have to remove the object you just dragged now, since you've changed the image of the corresponding cell
        }
```

How this works: The recogniser looks for the centre of the translation and finds out which cell it lies inside. It then accesses the imageView of that cell and changes the image to the target image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: finally I used the center of each uiimageview as the locator, and calculate the shortest dist from the image been dragged and any cell in the board, thus put the image into the cell which has the shortest dist to the center of the image. Your idea is good, thanks!